# How to Assert if field in NULL in JSON Response from SOAP UI

Tags: soapui

How to Assert if field in NULL  in JSON Response from SOAP UI

Example: Data looks like this I need to assert if Children is null using Assert option from Soap UI.

```
  {
  "request":    {
  "parameters": {"SOURCE_NAME":       {
     "name": "Members_Sheet1",
     "caseSensitivity": "CASE_SENSITIVE",
     "inputMatchingOperator": "EXACT"
  }},
  "metadata": {}
                },
        "data":    {
  "results": [{"data": {"Members_Sheet1":       [
              {
        "Sl No": 1,
        "Member ID": 70000001,
        "Member Name": "Fly Dorami",
        "Location": "New York",
        "DOB": "4/12/2008",
        "Gender": "M",
        "Marital Status": "Single",
        "Children": "",
        "Ethnicity": "Asian",
        "Insurance Plan ID": 2002,
        "Annual Income ($)": 0,
        "Twitter User ID": 548900028
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JSON you quoted is having empty string in Children, its not a NULL. For doing this you may need to convert the JSON to XML using ResponseAsXML property enabled.

Alternative is to use **groovy script assertion**;

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper 
def response = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def json = slurper.parseText response

// json variable has all your data
assert // statement
```

Comment: Thank you, emarshah. I did it like:
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper 
def response = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def responseText = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response.toString())

assert responseText == []